# Combine multiple query results into one row and add columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have searched extensively for this type of resolution but have not been able to find anything that works.

Here is my data:

```
Table1

co_num |  item id

L11400  | widget1

L11400  | widget2

L11400  | widget3

L11401  | widget1

L11401  | widget2
```

I would like to query the table and return the data like this:

```
co_num | itemid1 | itemid2 | itemid3

L11400 | widget1 | widget2 | widget3

L11401 | widget1 | widget2 | (blank)
```

Is this possible? I'm using SQL 2008. It does need to be dynamic because the number of items may vary. It would be best if this could possibly be down in a view/query.

Thanks

Comment: Look into sql server dynamic pivot.

Comment: @Mihai I have and cannot seem to get the syntax right. I'll look again.

Comment: At least put a sqlfiddle up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38804)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(co_num VARCHAR(20),itemid VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('L11400','widget1'),
('L11400','widget2'),
('L11400','widget3'),
('L11401','widget1'),
('L11401','widget2')

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
           ,'ItemID' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY co_num 
                                            ORDER BY itemid) AS VARCHAR(10)) Items
    FROM @TABLE
    ) t
PIVOT (MAX(itemid)
       FOR Items 
       IN ([ItemID1],[ItemID2],[ItemID3])
       )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38804/0)**:

```
| CO_NUM | ITEMID1 | ITEMID2 | ITEMID3 |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| L11400 | widget1 | widget2 | widget3 |
| L11401 | widget1 | widget2 |  (null) |
```

Comment: Perfect! My query ended up being a little more complex but this got me where I needed to go. Thank you!